# Inserting new table row after the first table row using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with `id="#table"` and then the first row with `id="headings"`, now directy after the heading row I need to insert a new row

I use the following code

`$("#headings").after($("#table").prepend("<tr>...</tr>"));`

but I think I'm doing something wrong here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `.after()`<sup>[ref](http://api.jquery.com/after/)</sup> and `.prepend()`<sup>[ref](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)</sup> require a "HTML string", a "DOM node" or a "jQuery" object as argument.

So it would be actually enough to call

```
$('#headings').after('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe `$("#table tr:first").after("<tr><td>some</td><td>content</tr></tr>");` may be easier? Here's [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rekTp/1/).