# How to prepend a tr to after first tr at a table?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, prepend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting new table row after the first table row using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849794/inserting-new-table-row-after-the-first-table-row-using-jquery)

I have populated a tr for my table and I want to prepend it after the firts tr. I use this:

```
$('#myTable').prepend($tr);
```

As usual, it adds my new tt to the top.

How can I add it as second?

Comment: Check out the jQuery API on the [first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Comment: I searched and my question is possible duplication. I found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849794/inserting-new-table-row-after-the-first-table-row-using-jquery

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You will want to use jquery [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/), like this:

```
$('#myTable tr:first').after($tr);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do one thing keep the first tr to `<thead>` of the table and rest tr to `<tbody>` of the table.

Now do

```
$('#myTable tbody').prepend($tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('#myTable > tbody > tr:first').after($tr);
```